# Partial order with an unusual relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

Determine whether $(V,E)$ is a partial order. $V = \{a, b, c, d\}$ $E = \{(a, b), (b, c), (c, d), (a, c), (a, d), (b, d)\}$

I am confused since the definition of partial order says:

> A partial order (PO) $(D,\sqsubseteq)$ consists of a set $D$, called domain,
>   and of a relation $\sqsubseteq \subseteq D \times D$ such that for every $d1, d2, d3 \in D$
>   we have:
>
> - Reflexivity: $d1 \sqsubseteq d1$
> - Transitivity: $d1 \sqsubseteq d2 \land d2 \sqsubseteq d3 \Rightarrow d1 \sqsubseteq d3$
> - Antisymmetry: $d1 \sqsubseteq d2 \land d2 \sqsubseteq d1 \Rightarrow d1 = d2$

Now, when I look at the given $E$, I don't understand how is it a relation. How can I use it like if it was let's say relation $<$? Where I can simply see if $d1 < d2$ for example?

Comment: $(x, y) \in E$ is written in *infix notation* as $xEy$.

Comment: I still don't understand. So, how would you solve this problem? I still don't understand what does this given relation mean

Comment: E is a subset of V×V.  That's all it takes for E to be a relation for V.

Comment: Ok, then how do you show that it is not or that it is, for example antisymmetric? I am so sorry, but I am still confused. So far all other examples I've managed to find were something like: Determine whether $(\Bbb N, \leq)$ is a partial order.

Comment: $d_1 < d_2$ if and only if $(d_1,d_2) \in E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary relation $E$ on a set $V$ is rigorously defined as a *set of pairs* of elements of $V$, and the notation $x~E~y$ stands for $(x,y)\in E$.

Said that, now we have $a~E~b~E~c~E~d$, and 3 more: $a~E~c, \ a~E~d, \ b~E~d$, which lead to the transitivity of $E$. 
You can also verify antisymmetry of $E$. 
However, $E$ is *not reflexive*, as none of the following holds (though all should):
$$a~E~a, \ b~E~b, \ c~E~c, \ d~E~d$$
So, $E$ is *not a partial order*.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I've got it now.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is the relation $a < b$ if $(a,b) \in E$.

So $a \sqsubseteq b; b\sqsubseteq c; c\sqsubseteq d; a\sqsubseteq c; a\sqsubseteq d; a\sqsubseteq d$.

And that's it.  That is a list of *every* element that is related to *any* other element.

Is is it reflexive? Does $x \sqsubseteq x$ for all $x\in V$?  In other words is $(x,x) \in E$ for all $x\in V$?

Is it reflexive.  For an $x\sqsubseteq y$ and $y \sqsubseteq z$ do we always have $x\sqsubseteq z$.  That is; if $(x,y)\in E$ and $(y,z) \in E$ do we always have $(x,y) \in Z$?

Is it anti reflexive.  If $x \sqsubseteq y$ and $y\sqsubseteq x$ does it always follow that $x =y$.  Or if $(x,y),(y,x)\in E$ does that only happen when $x=y$?

Answer:

> It's not reflexive.  We do not have any of $a\sqsubseteq a$ or $b\sqsubseteq b$ or $c\sqsubseteq c$ or $d\sqsubseteq d$.  It does seem to be transitive.  Indeed it seems to be $x \sqsubseteq y\iff y$ is higher in the alphabet than $x$.  And it is antisymetric as we *never* have any $x\sqsubseteq y$ and $y\sqsubseteq x$.

.

> So anyway it isn't a partial as we don't have reflexivity.